# Is this hard drive new?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I got a new external hard drive (a 4TB Seagate magnetic HDD, factory formatted with exFAT, if this matters) that came completely initialized with random data.

As in the past I found one badly damaged drive, I started testing the disks by reading from and writing to a few points in the disk to find obvious faults. When reading data from a fresh HDD, I had found that most bytes of the disks were initialized with zeros, except of course those set up during formatting and adding manufacturer files. However, in this case I found out that the disk was formatted correctly but otherwise initialized with random data (or at least looks random and doesn't compress), instead of having zeros in empty sectors.

As a quick Google search didn't turn up anything related and this is different from most disks, I'm curious as to why this happens. Is this something that can happen during manufacture? Was the disk used and then rewritten with random data to avoid recovery? Or is there some other reason?

Comment: It would be recommended to view the S.M.A.R.T data via [`smartmontools`](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download#InstalltheWindowspackage); it's common practice to do a burn-in when a drive will be installed within an NAS [via `smartlctl`] and would be more efficient than a few random r/w. OEMs do write to all drives once they're assembled to test the drives, with some external drives coming pre-initialized and pre-formatted from the OEM _(product info would state so)_, but I don't believe the same is true for internal drives.

Answer (score 1):

> I started testing the disks by reading from and writing to a few
> points in the disk to find obvious faults. When reading data from a
> fresh HDD, I had found that most bytes of the disks were initialized
> with zeros,

When I buy a new, good quality hard drive, there are no errors on the drive. That has been true for some years.

A new drive needs to be initialized as a drive (still blank) and then formatted. No errors at that point for me.

So I suggest the drive is either not new, or has been reconditioned/remanufactured  (new controller card and test) to sell as "new". Data may have been left over from such a drive.

I suggest returning it and purchasing another drive.

Comment: Is the disk being initialized with random data instead of zeros an error by itself (or in any case suggests data was written to the disk before)?

Comment: High quality drives are not initialized with data to the best of my knowledge. They need to be initialized as a drive (still blank) and then formatted. No errors at that point.

Comment: It would be recommended to view the S.M.A.R.T data via [`smartmontools`](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download#InstalltheWindowspackage) prior to an RMA. OEMs do write to all drives once they're assembled to test the drives. Some external drives do come pre-initialized _(product info would state so)_, but I don't believe the same is true for internal drives.

Answer (score 0):

If the disk has random data on it out the box, its not new. It was either overwritten with random data or used in a device with bitlocker or similar.

Sometime SMART information on the disk can give hints as to its age by advising its condition and power up time.